# Suite Script 2.0 - List all the Saved Search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

Is there any way to get list of all the Transaction's Saved Search that I have created on NetSuite using Suite Script 2.0. Please see attached screen shot.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a search of saved searches. You can run the following in your browser console to test, and modify to suit what you need:

```
require(['N/search'], function (search) {
  var savedSearches = search.create({
      type: search.Type.SAVED_SEARCH,
      filters: [
        ['recordtype','is','Transaction']
      ],
      columns: [
            search.createColumn({
                name: 'id'
            }),
            search.createColumn({
                name: 'title'
            }),
            search.createColumn({
               name: 'recordtype'
            })
       ]
    });
    savedSearches.run().each(
        function(r) {
           var a = r.getValue({
               name:'id'
               });
           var b = r.getValue({
               name:'title'
               });
           var c = r.getValue({
               name:'recordtype'
           });
           console.log(a + ' | ' + b + ' | ' + c);
           return true;
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Just 1 more question related to this, if I want to get all the columns (not only Id, title, recordtype) what should I do. I have tried by passing empty array for columns, but not worked for me.

Comment: You can add each column explicitly: `var x = r.getValue({name:'columnName'});` or `var x = r.getText({name:'columnName'});` for list/record fields where you want to return the text rather than the id (value) or you could iterate through all the columns with something like `savedSearches.run().each(function (result) {result.columns.forEach(function (column) { row[column.label] = result.getText(column) || result.getValue(column); });`  I haven't tested that last one, but have used similar in the past.  This returns the text if it exists, otherwise it returns the value.